# What are the components in the ruby statement

Tags: ruby, fastlane

I am new to Ruby . While using fastlane for iOS , in the fastfile I see the below statement

```
lane :mybuildlane do
```

end

Is lane a type?
What does the  colon before  mybuildlane indicate ?
Is mybuildlane closure name ?

For those who are down voting , please make a comment why are you doing so . 
I did my research before asking this question ?

Comment: I'd probably take a step back and spin through some Ruby tutorials-take things one step at a time; it'll be quicker in the long run if you learn some basics first.

Comment: Please, read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/2988 to understand why "Explain this code to me" questions are off-topic. "isn’t the purpose of community to help each other?" – No, the purpose of this community is to provide a repository of canonical, objectively verifiable, correct, high-quality knowledge for professional software developers. Copy&pasting a basic introduction to Ruby does not increase the sum total knowledge of the software development community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lane` is the name of a [method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_methods.htm), which you are invoking.

`:mybuildlane` is a [`Symbol`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html); one of the basic data types in ruby.

`do ... end`, or `{` ... `}` indicates a *block* (a type of closure).

What is the code actually **doing**? I'd need to see the whole context, and read the gem's documentation, to tell you that!

Comment: The symbol has to be defined somewhere right ? Or is it the detention between do end

Comment: @rajeshsukumaran A symbol in Ruby is kind of like a string. Writing `:mybuildlane` is kind of like writing `"mybuildlane"`: it doesn't need to be defined before to be used. The `lane` method probably knows how to do something with it, however, like Tom, I don't know off hand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

This is a call for a ruby method with a block of code.

`lane` is the method called

`:mybuildlane` is a symbol that entry into method for some process

`do` is represented for `do ... end` that is the same in ruby for `{ ... }` and it is reference to a block of code. [See this link and you can lern more about this type of method calls](https://mixandgo.com/learn/mastering-ruby-blocks-in-less-than-5-minutes)

Comment: Strictly speaking, `do`-`end` is not **exactly** the same as `{`-`}`, they have different precedence.